# ontouch event issues

Tags: javascript, events, touch, handler

I have a little question of the touch handler...it sometimes work on touch sometimes not, and it cant read my data after i draw it, and it draw with straight line, so i wonder what problem and what i did wrong? please help me..i already put my code into jsfiddle..please help me (http://jsfiddle.net/Frebu/1/)

```
function touchHandler(event) {
        var touches = event.changedTouches,
        first = touches[0],
        type = "";
        switch (event.type) {
            case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
            case "touchmove": type = "mousemove"; break;
            case "touchend": type = "mouseup"; break;
            default: return;
        }

        var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
        simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1,
                      first.screenX, first.screenY,
                      first.clientX, first.clientY, false,
                      false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);

        first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    function init(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
    }
$(document).ready(function() {
        init('myCanvas');
});​
```

Comment: here my whole snippet codes..http://jsfiddle.net/Frebu/1/

Comment: You misspelled `ontouchstart` as `oontouchstart` in the HTML, but I don't think that's the problem. There's a stack overflow somewhere.

Comment: ya..thats not an issue, i just don know why sometimes work fine and now it cant read and generate the drawing data on touch devices such as ipad

Answer (score 1):

My recomendation is to use hammer.js, it's a great touch library (that fallbacks to mouse on browsers).

http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/

Aside from that, i didn't have any issues testing the fiddle on Chrome simulating touch events. And altought weird, the code seems to be fine.

Comment: ya..its weird, can you get the data from the textarea?